# Ranking Based on a number of conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dt

I am looking to form a ranking that is dependent on a pairing. So say i have a matrix

```
    subject stim1 stim2 Chosen Tchosen
 1:       1    34    35     34      32
 2:       1    34    36     34      25
 3:       1    34    36     36       6
 4:       1    35    37     35      19
 5:       1    35    37     37      13
 6:       1    36    38     36       9
 7:       1    36    38     38      22
 8:       1    37    39     37      29
 9:       1    37    39     39       2
10:       1    38    39     38      25
11:       1    38    39     39       6
```

My objective is for each subject to rank each stimuli with a ranking of either 1,2 or 3 based on Tchosen. The catch is that it is ranked only relative to the other two options (i.e. only stim1 stim2 pairings are relevant for the ranking).

For example, for stim1=34, it is chosen more times than either 35 or 36 (for stim1=34 stim2=35, Chosen=34 has a higher Tchosen than the TChosen for Chosen=36) and therefore should have a rank 1.

Separately, I look at 36. 36 is paired with 34 and 38. It is chosen less frequently than 34 and less frequently than 38 and therefore has a rank 3.

Separately I look at stim1=37. 37 is paired with 35 and 39. 37 is chosen less frequently than 35 but more frequently than 39 and therefore has a rank 2

Desired output

```
subject stim Rank 
1        34   1
1        35   2
1        36   3
1        37   2
1        38   1
1        39   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea.
The main thought is, less losses (loss = another stim was chosen) means higher rank. So stims always chosen get rank 1, stims never chosen got last rank. Therefore I created a column `diff`, indicating who got chosen more often. Positive diffs mean `stim1` got chosen more often, negative diffs mean `stim2` got chosen more often. And then I sumed the times a certain stim lossed (wasn't chosen over another stim). In the end stims with 0 losses (stim was always chosen) got rank 1, and for each loss the stim ranked one step below.

**Code**

```
df %>% 
  #transform table 
  # subjecct - stim1 - stim2 - votes for stim1 (Tc1) -
  # votes for stim2 (Tc2)
  group_by(subject, stim1, stim2) %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(stim1 == Chosen, 1, 2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -c(Tchosen, id, Chosen ),
              names_from = id, 
              names_prefix = "Tc",
              values_from = c(Tchosen),
              values_fill = 0) %>%
  #how many votes got stim1 over stim2 
  #(positive diff - stim1 got more votes, 
  #negative ifff - stim2 go more votes)
  mutate(diff = Tc1- Tc2) %>%
  # transformed stims into long format
  pivot_longer(cols = c(stim1, stim2),
               values_to = "stim") %>% 
  group_by(subject, stim) %>%
  # how often was another stim chosen
  summarise(loss = sum(name == "stim1" & diff < 0 |  
                        name  == "stim2" & diff > 0 )
            )%>%
  # rank losses (less losses - higher rank)
  mutate(rank = loss + 1)  %>%
  select(-loss)
```

**Output**

```
 A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   subject [1]
  subject  stim  rank
    <int> <int> <dbl>
1       1    34     1
2       1    35     2
3       1    36     3
4       1    37     2
5       1    38     1
6       1    39     3
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), stim1 = c(34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
38L, 38L), stim2 = c(35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L), Chosen = c(34L, 34L, 36L, 35L, 37L, 36L, 38L, 
37L, 39L, 38L, 39L), Tchosen = c(32L, 25L, 6L, 19L, 13L, 9L, 
22L, 29L, 2L, 25L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:", "7:", "8:", "9:", "10:", "11:"))
```